# Beamer: Same figure number for the same figure on all frames

Tags: beamer, captions

Is it possible to get the same figure number for the same image, when it is used on more than one frame? (Wouldn't mind to change the figure number manually)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two relatively simple options: beamer's `\againframe` (section 11.2 of [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)), or [manipulating the figure counter](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=809):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=A]
The original frame
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\label{fig:example}Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
A second frame
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\againframe{A}

\begin{frame}
A third frame
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
A slightly different frame with a repeated image from the first frame
% Ref: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=809
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\renewcommand\thefigure{1}
\caption{Caption}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
A fourth frame
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]